# Server 2008 R2 - restoring a user's roaming profile folder from Previous Versions

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, restore

I want to restore a user's roaming profile folder from previous versions, but having no luck. I keep running into access rights problems.

The previous version was created with the default rights set on the .V2 folder, I have a policy in place that is supposed to give admins access to the .V2 folders, however, as I am finding out now, that policy is not functioning correctly apparently.

I am stuck now with a previous version of the .V2 folder I cannot copy or access. I can open the Profiles folder in the previous folder pane and see the folder, but have no access.

Is there a way to reset the permissions of the folder inside the previous versions folder? I've considered/tried cacls, but that doesn't have the desired result.

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand your question, but previous versions (VSS snapshots) are stored in the "system information volume" folder of the drive in question. Do you know if anyone messed with the permissions of this folder?

Answer (score 0):

The way I've solved this is by accessing the network share where the roaming profile is stored from within the user's account on a client PC. This should let you open and restore previous versions of the profile.